# passing parameter from java script on input html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem with passing javascript variable as value on input hidden type on html form.

For more details :

```
  public function exportToPdf1($headerText=""){

    // serialize the grid object into the session
    $_SESSION[$this->viewPaneId."-pdf"] = serialize($this);


    $pfdExport .= ' // create the export to pdf button
    $("#'.$this->getViewPaneId().'").prepend("<div id=\"pdfExport\"       style=\"float:right; border: none; cursor:pointer;\"><img src=\"images/stock_save_pdf.png\"> </div>");';

    $pfdExport.=' // onClick function
             var printToPdf = false;
             var selectedRowId;

    $("#pdfExport").click(function(){

           selectedRowId  = $("#'.$this->getViewPaneId().'input[name=\'rowSelectionRadio\']:checked").val();


       if(selectedRowId){    

            if(confirm("Are you sure to print this object ?")){
                printToPdf = true;
            }

        }else{
            printToPdf = false;
            alert("Please select an element from the table first.");
        }



            // create a temporarly form, in order to POST the data
            $("<form id=\"pdf-form\" method=\"post\" action=\"index.php?c=gridToPdf\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"gridObjId\" value=\"'.$this->viewPaneId.'\"></form>").appendTo("#rightcolumn");
            $("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"headerText\" value=\"'.$headerText.'\">").appendTo("#pdf-form");
              $("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"act\" value=\"exportObject\">").appendTo("#pdf-form");
              $("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rId\" value=\"'.selectedRowId.'\" >").appendTo("#pdf-form");


            // submit the form and remove it
            $("#pdf-form").submit().remove();
        }
    });';
```

Always rId gets as value string "selectedRowId", not the value of the selectedRowId var.
have any anyone any idea  how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, `selectedRowId` doesn't seem to be defined and `selectedRowId` is also no valid variable in php, thats why the input field has the value `selectedRowId` as php thinks its a string rather than a variable.

/edit-> okey, I see that `selectedRowId` is a javascript variable and not a php variable. So you will need to to use "+" for concatination rather than "." and

Comment: Thanks for yours answer, I try with "+" but didn't work again.

Comment: I modify $("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rId\" value=\"'.selectedRowId.'\" >") as $("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rId\" id=\"rId\" value=\"\" >")...;  and i have added document.getElementById("rId").value=+selectedRowId; this solved my problem :)